# Expected value of elevator's last stop with $k$ floors and $n$ passengers.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value, poisson-distribution

The number of people, $n$, who enter an elevator with $k$ floors follows a Poisson distribution with a mean of $10$. Each person has an equal probability of getting off on any given floor, independent of the others. What is the expected value of the **last** floor that the elevator stops at?

I first tried having $X=\text{number of floors}$ and $X \sim NB(n, \frac{1}{k})$, except that isn't correct, since $E(X)$ would end up being $nk$, and $k$ is the maximum last floor.

Comment: Well, why not start with a simpler problem?  Suppose $n$ people get on (for some fixed $n$).  What's the expected value of the last floor the elevator stops at?  If that's too hard, try it for $n=1$.  Then $n=2$. and so on, until you see a way to do it generally.

Comment: Doing this, I got E(X) = $\frac{n-1}{2}\sum_{x=1}^{k}\frac{x(x+1)}{k^{x+1}}$. Since I am finding E(X), can I set n = 10, since we know this is the average value of n?

Comment: Not following. $E[X]$ should depend on $n,k$ only.  It can't depend on $X$.  And this, simpler, problem has nothing to do with the Poisson side, so the mean of $10$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, well I think my following answer is probably too complicated, but here is what I tried. $E(X)=\sum_{x=1}^{k}xp_X(x)$. $$p_X(x)=P(\text{a passenger gets off at floor }x)\sum_{i_1}^{x}\ldots\sum_{i_{n-1}}^{x}P(\text{others get off at }i_1 \cap \ldots i_{n-1})$$ In other words, the all of the possible cases where at least one person gets off at x. $$P(\text{someone gets off at }x) = (\frac{k-1}{k})^{x-1}\frac{1}{k}$$ $$P(\text{others get off at }i_1 \cup \ldots i_{n-1})=\frac{1}{k}((\frac{k-1}{k})^{(n-1)k-i_1-\ldots -i_{n-1}})$$ Putting these together would get E(X), but idk how to do the sum

Comment: Sorry for the small parentheses, I ran out of characters

Comment: @CarterKarlFalkenberg going forward I suggest you edit your efforts into your original post so it doesn't attract downvotes.

Comment: Noted, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $N$ passengers enter the elevator.

If $M\in \{1,...,k\}$ is the last floor the elevator stopped at, then at least one passenger got off at floor $M$ and those passengers who didn't exit floor $M$ got off at an earlier floor. So, for $m\in \{1,...,n\}$ $$\mathbb{P}(M=m)=\sum_{l=1}^N{N \choose l}\Big({1 \over k}\Big)^l\Big(\frac{m-1}{k}\Big)^{N-l}$$ The index $l$ signifies the number of passengers who exited the $m^{\text{th}}$ floor. Using the binomial theorem we can write this as $$\mathbb{P}(M=m)=\Big(\frac{m}{k}\Big)^N-\Big(\frac{m-1}{k}\Big)^{N}$$ The above pdf is the *conditional* pdf of $M$ given $N\sim \text{Poisson}(10)$ whose expected value is $$\mathbb{E}(M|N)=\sum_{m=1}^k m\Bigg[\Big(\frac{m}{k}\Big)^N-\Big(\frac{m-1}{k}\Big)^{N}\Bigg]=k-\sum_{m=1}^k\Big(\frac{m-1}{k}\Big)^N$$ Using double expectation and a whole bunch of calculus, $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{E}(M)&=&\mathbb{E}\Big(\mathbb{E}(M|N)\Big)\\&=& \mathbb{E}\Bigg(k-\sum_{m=1}^k\Big(\frac{m-1}{k}\Big)^N\Bigg) \\ &=& k-\sum_{m=1}^k\mathbb{E}\bigg(\Big(\frac{m-1}{k}\Big)^N\bigg) \\ &=& k - \sum_{m=1}^k \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{m-1}{k}\Big)^n\cdot e^{-10}\frac{10^n}{n!} \\ &=& k-\sum_{m=1}^k \exp\Big(\frac{10(m-k-1)}{k}\Big)\\ &=& k+\frac{e^{-10}-1}{e^{10/k}-1}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think to use the sum of a binomial distribution... makes sense.